# Can I use scrollTo in order to fix slideToggle footer issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto, slidetoggle

I'm trying to create a footer that will slide from the bottom of the page when a link is clicked. The footer will slide out (using slideToggle) however it is not visible until you scroll down. I'm pretty sure what I want to do is use scrollTo so that when the link is clicked it instantly scrolls to the bottom while the footer slides up. I'm not sure how this is accomplished.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.footermenu').hide();  
$('.footertoggle').click(function() {
$('.footermenu').slideToggle(400);
return false;
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.footermenu').hide();  
$('.footertoggle').click(function() {
$('.footermenu').slideToggle(400);
//add this line
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#footer").offset().top},'slow');
return false;
});
});
```